# Semi transparent div

Tags: html, css

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/F4sYM/

## EDITED

Here is the new code: http://jsfiddle.net/F4sYM/5/

I'm trying to remove the `#header` opacity when `#main` overlaps it.

Since I'm using an image that uses `background-size` property, I can't just create another div inside `#main`.

Sample:

[image: I want the exactly opposite from what I got.]

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: So the only thing u want to see from the #main container when it overlaps the #header is the shadow from the borders, is this correct?

Comment: This question needs better definition. Please provide screenshots of the result you would like to see.

Comment: No... take a look at the new code. I want to do the inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opacity is inherited and cannot be simply removed.

```
.notranscolor -> opacity: 0.5 * 1.0 = 0.5
```

Solution:

Absolutly position contents.

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano I was just about to post solution using 3 divs -- http://jsfiddle.net/7e3BG/

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
background: inherit;
```

for `#main` div. You can also specify any other background-color explicitly.

http://jsfiddle.net/F4sYM/3/

EDIT:

removing

```
position: relative;
```

for #main div seems to have done it.

http://jsfiddle.net/F4sYM/7/

EDIT 2:

solution using 3 divs:

http://jsfiddle.net/7e3BG/

Comment: That is not what I'm looking for... I want to show the "original" red color when #main overlaps it (without opacity).

Comment: I've uploaded a picture, please take a look

Comment: What I want is as simple as invert:

transparent areas become opaque; opaque areas become transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand what exactly you need to achieve....
Is there any chance you can quickly make a screenshot of the result you want to achieve?

Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F4sYM/6/)** even though i don't think that's what you want...

I just reverted the index

```
z-index: 0;
```

Comment: I've added a screenshot.